# Using pd.apply() to turn each element in a column to a list, grab the 1st element, and turn it into datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I have a dataframe with only one row (in the future, it will be more, but I am just using this as an example). I am trying to grab the "SETTLEMENT_DATE" column.

`print(previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"])`

`0    2021-06-22 00:00:00.0`

`Name: SETTLEMENT_DATE, dtype: object`.

In order to get the date, I did `list(previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"])[0]`, which yields:
`'2021-06-22 00:00:00.0'`. Now I turn this into a date format using:

`def create_datetime_object(pd_object):`

```
date_time_str = list(pd_object)[0]
return datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

This code: `create_datetime_object(previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"])`

yields: `datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 0, 0)`

In the future, I will have multiple rows of data, so I wanted to use pd.apply() to apply this function to the entire column. But when I do that, I get:

`previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"] = previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"].apply(create_datetime_object)`

`ValueError: time data '2' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"] = previous.apply(lambda r : create_datetime_object(r.SETTLEMENT_DATE) , axis=1)
```

Comment: I think because my dataframe only contains one row, previous["SETTLEMENT_DATE"] is actually a series? When I run this, I get: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Indeed if it is a series it will not work. However, when you will have a dataframe with many rows, this code will work.

Comment: Okay great. Looks I will just have to create an if else statment to account for the cases where a df might only contain one row. There should be cases where I have many rows, and only one row in the df, depending on the day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update: this code actually doesn't work. Df["column"].apply(lambda, axis = 1) will cause an error because  Df["column"] is a series. but Df.apply(lambda x:function(x['col'],axis=1) will work.